# Im just playing around with HTML but when I load my code, I get an error. Error Code: Out of Memory

Tags: javascript, html, memory

the code is short and it cant be because of outdated systems as this laptop was bought 4 months ago. 
Every time I click on the index.html file it takes 50 seconds to load and then I get the error. I am not sure what else to do as the Microsoft Help Team was useless. I am not sure if there are any errors in the code as I can't run it. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>A canvas</title>
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">
      canvas {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
  </style>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="1000px" width="1000px"></canvas>
    <script>

        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onDown, false);

        var fireWall = false;
        var score = 0;

        while (score != 10){
          c.font = "30px Comic Sans MS"
          c.fillText(score, 500, 200)
          c.font = "30px Comic Sans MS"
          c.fillText("Click the Screen 10 Times to Win the Hardest Game Ever!!!", 50,300);

          function onDown(){
            console.log('working')
            c.score++;
            }

          if(score === 10){
              fireWall = true;
              break;
          }
        }

        if(fireWall === true){
            c.fill(255, 153, 0);
            c.noStroke();
            c.ellipse(mouseX-90, mouseY-30, 75, 25);
            c.ellipse(mouseX-90, mouseY-80, 85, 35);
            c.rect(mouseX-103, mouseY-80, 25,45);
            c.rect(mouseX-132, mouseY-155, 85,75);
            c.textSize(50);
            c.fill(255,0,0);
            c.text("YOU WON", mouseX-205, mouseY-170);
        }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

com/jywPv.png

Comment: Your `while` loop never changes the value of `score`. It will therefore never exit.

Comment: Never put functions inside loops.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const c = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

const game = { // You could use an Object literal to store stuff
  fireWall: false,
  score: 0,
  mouseX: 0,
  mouseY: 0,
};

const draw = () => { // Create a function to handle drawing

  // Don't forget to clear the canvas before painting
  c.clearRect(0, 0, c.canvas.width, c.canvas.height);
  c.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
  
  if (game.fireWall) {
    c.fillText("YOU WON", game.mouseX-80, game.mouseY-5);
  } else {
    c.fillText(game.score, 500, 200); // Retrieve the score from game Object
    c.fillText("Click the Screen 10 Times to Win the Hardest Game Ever!!!", 50, 300);
  }
}

const onDown = (ev) => { // Don't forget the ev Event!

  if (game.fireWall) return; // Prevent additional clicks if firewall reached

  const bcr = c.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  game.mouseX = ev.clientX - bcr.x;
  game.mouseY = ev.clientY - bcr.y;
  game.score++;

  if (game.score >= 10) {
    game.fireWall = true;
  }
  draw();
}

draw(); // First draw!
c.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onDown); // And draw on click
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="1000px" width="1000px"></canvas>
```